# MYSQL converting slow update with subquery to (faster?) join

Tags: mysql, performance, join, subquery

I have a query that uses a subquery in mysql that gets very slow, taking up to a few minutes while all other querys i do are quite fast.

As i found out subquerys are most likely a bad idea so i wanted to convert 
this subquery to a join like i did with all my other querys that used subquerys with big impacts on performance.

Most of my other querys where quite simple but this one drives me nuts.

Here is an example.

I have clients and bills. Clients have multiple bills. Bills have states. And bills have a parameter "whatever".

I need to update
"all clients where all bills are in state 1 or 2 and that bills whatever-parameter is not 2"

Since i couldnt find out how to do that i used the invert which is
 "all clients that have no bills  that are not in state 1 and not in state 2 and that bills whatever-parameter is not 2"

These are the two variants with subquerys i am using right now,one using count and one using "not in", but they seem to be equally slow.

```
update client cl , bill bi 
set cl.parameter = "parameter1" 
where cl.parameter="parameter2" 
    and bi.whatever != "2" 
    and bi.client_id = cl.id  
    and (select count(cl.id) 
            from bill bi 
                where bi.client_id = cl.id 
                    and bi.state!="state0" 
                    and bi.state != "state1" 
        ) = 0;
```

gets slow in mysql state "sending data"

```
update client cl , bill bi 
set cl.parameter = "parameter1"  
    where  cl.parameter="parameter2" 
        and bi.whatever != "2" 
        and bi.client_id = cl.id  
        and cl.id not in  (select distinct cl.id 
                                from bill bi  
                                    where bi.client_id = cl.id 
                                        and  ( bi.state!="state1" 
                                        and bi.state != "state2" 
                            ) ;
```

gets slow in mysql state "copying to temp table"

I tried for hours but i couldn't convert this to something usefull without that slow subquery. 
 Can anyone give me an idea how to do this using a join or something faster than now?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to DRapp, this produces the exact same results and is much faster. For what i could test till now query time is down to a few seconds, and it was a few minutes before.

```
select
  c.id,
  sum( if( b.State IN ( "State1", "State2" ), 1, 0 )) as OkStatesCnt,
  sum( if( b.State NOT IN ( "State1", "State2" ) or b.whatever=2, 1, 0 )  ) as AnyOtherState
from
  client c
     join bill b
        ON c.id = b.client_id
where
  c.parameter = "parameter2"
   group by
      c.id
  having
      OkStatesCnt > 0
  AND AnyOtherState = 0
```

And

```
UPDATE client cl,
  ( full select query from above ) as PreQualified
 set cl.parameter = "parameter1"
 where cl.id = PreQualified.id
```

Comment: Can you please confirm the following... It looks like you want to update all clients who EXIST in the Bill table... AND are NOT in "state1" or "state2".. as the result of a cl.id NOT IN and looking for Bill clients NOT State1 or State1.

Comment: i want to update all clients who have bills (bill has reference to client.id) AND where all bills are in state 1 or in state 2. which means no more bills are in any other state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To pre-ensure WHAT clients will be included, you can run this query on its own...

```
select
      c.id,
      sum( if( b.State IN ( "State1", "State2" ), 1, 0 )) as OkStatesCnt,
      sum( if( b.State IN ( "State1", "State2" ), 0, 1 )) as AnyOtherState
   from
      client c
         join bill b
            ON c.id = b.client_id
           AND b.whatever != "2"
   where
      c.parameter = "parameter2"
       group by
          c.id
   having
          OkStatesCnt > 0
      AND AnyOtherState = 0
```

IF this in-fact IS what you are looking for, you can just implement into your update like

```
UPDATE client cl,
      ( full select query from above ) as PreQualified
   set cl.parameter = "parameter1"
   where cl.id = PreQualified.id
```

Comment: hm.. this gives me all clients that have bills that are not state1 and not in state 2. But i need all clients where all bills are in state 1 or in state 2, and no bill is in any other state. This is why i used the invert with count in the first and "not in" in the second query.

Comment: @dirk, check revision.  The inner query does a count of OK states and another of AnyOther state.  The HAVING will qualify AT LEAST the Ok State and the AnyOther count = 0.  Only issue I don't know how to apply is when the "whatever != '2'" component.  Do you only want != '2' entries considered for the counts, or only those of State1 / State2, but hope this gives you a jump and I can help narrow down this result for you.

Comment: ah, thank you very much, thats quite it. however i have put that b.whatever!=2 into " sum( if( b.state NOT IN ( "state1","state2") or b.whatever=2, 1 , 0)) as AnyOtherState".That models my old query exactly.  I will update my question now to include the answer. Thanks again!